# Kibana WAU bar chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-6, kibana-6

I have an elastic index with logs, and one of the logs is that a user visited the app.

I am trying to create a WAU Bar Chart (Weekly Active Users) and I want the X-axis to be days. and for each day I want to see how many users visited the app during the 7 day timeframe ending with that day.

For example, for the X point 27/08, I want the see the visit count for 20/08-27/08.
I can't seem to figure out how to make this graph, does anyone have an idea? or is it impossible?

Comment: this means that a user visiting on the 25/08 will be counted once for the bar on 25/08, once for the bar on 26/08 and another time for the bar on 27/08 ?

Comment: Yes, a visit will be counted several times

Comment: it is possible, let me explain that properly in an answer.

Comment: thanks. waiting for your answer